# How do I override default extension in SystemJS with *no* extension?

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I have a javascript bundle that's made available without a '.js' extension, so when SystemJS tries to import `bundles/main.js` it throws a 404.

I've tried to establish that these bundles have no extension by adding a `defaultExtension: ''`, but to no avail.

Here's the System.import line

```
System.import("bundles/main")
```

and my config.js

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },  
  packages: {
    'bundles/main': {
      format: 'js',
      defaultExtension: ''
    }
  },
  meta: {
    "Scripts/vendor/*": {
      "format": "global"
    },
    ...
```

**EDIT**

Note that the issue is that SystemJS is looking for `bundles/main.js` ... NOT `bundles/main` as it should be

Comment: Have you looked at what `404` means.... Does not exist/cannot be found. I think the best thing to do is try output the path so you can double check it is correct and targeting the file.

Comment: The path is verifiably *incorrect* -- I need to be able to override the defaultJSExtensions so that it does not append '.js' to the path